# Get sum of two columns based on conditions of other columns in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {"Subject":["1","2","3","3","4","5","5"],
        "date": ["2020-05-01 16:54:25","2020-05-03 10:31:18","2020-05-08 10:10:40","2020-05-08 10:10:42","2020-05-06 09:30:40","2020-05-07 12:46:30","2020-05-07 12:55:10"],
        "Accept": ["True","False","True","True","False","True","True"],
        "Amount" : [150,30,32,32,300,100,50],
        "accept_1": ["True","False","True","True","False","True","True"],
        "amount_1" : [20,30,32,32,150,100,30]}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I want to grouby the data by *Subject* and *date* and proceed to calculate for each *subject*,
the total sum of *Amount* and *amount_1* if *Accept* and *accept_1* are both True.

Here the True/False are not boolean but strings.

I have tried the following code:

```
def PPP(tx_amount_1,tx_accepted_1,tx_amount,tx_accepted):
if tx_accepted_1 and tx_accepted == "True":
    return tx_amount + tx_amount_1

example = data.groupby(["Subject","date"]) 
[["Accept","Amount","accept_1","amount_1"]].apply(lambda 
x: PPP(x["amount_1"],x["accept_1"],x["Amount"],x["Accept"]))
```

and I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() 
or a.all().
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, first slice the rows matching the condition by [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), then perform a [`GroupBy.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.sum.html):

```
mask = data['Accept'].eq('True') & data['accept_1'].eq('True')
data[mask].groupby(['Subject', pd.to_datetime(data['date']).dt.normalize()]).sum()
```

output:

```
                    Amount  amount_1
Subject date                        
1       2020-05-01     150        20
3       2020-05-08      64        64
5       2020-05-07     150       130
```

If you want a grand-total:

```
mask = data['Accept'].eq('True') & data['accept_1'].eq('True')
(data[mask]
 .groupby(['Subject', pd.to_datetime(data['date']).dt.normalize()])
 .sum().sum(axis=1)
 .reset_index(name='Total')
)
```

output:

```
  Subject       date  Total
0       1 2020-05-01    170
1       3 2020-05-08    128
2       5 2020-05-07    280
```

##### keep non matching conditions as 0

```
mask = data['Accept'].eq('True') & data['accept_1'].eq('True')
cols = ['Amount', 'amount_1']
(data
 .assign(**{c: data[c].where(mask, 0) for c in cols})
 .groupby(['Subject', pd.to_datetime(data['date']).dt.normalize()])
 .sum()
 #.sum(axis=1).reset_index(name='Total') # uncomment for grand-total
)
```

output:

```
                    Amount  amount_1
Subject date                        
1       2020-05-01     150        20
2       2020-05-03       0         0
3       2020-05-08      64        64
4       2020-05-06       0         0
5       2020-05-07     150       130
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked. How can put 0 as the sum to all the subjects whose accept and accept_1 columns are false?

Comment: See update, you just need to mask instead of slicing